# Is there a Windows equivilant to the Unix/Linux which statement?

Tags: windows, unix

The Unix which statement is very useful in determening which path is used for program run from the command line, and it would be very helpful to have something similar in windows.

Comment: Post up on stackoverflow.com and maybe somebody would write one for you.  :-)  I imagine it'd be fairly trivial.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Save this to a file named `which.cmd`:

```
@for %%e in (%PATHEXT%) do @for %%i in (%1%%e) do @if NOT "%%~$PATH:i"=="" echo %%~$PATH:i
@for %%i in (%1) do @if NOT "%%~$PATH:i"=="" echo %%~$PATH:i
```

Or download [UnxUtils](http://sourceforge.net/projects/unxutils) - they have lightweight native ports of the most common tools.

Or if you don't care about lightweightness, install Microsoft [Services For Unix](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=896c9688-601b-44f1-81a4-02878ff11778&DisplayLang=en). Yes, it has Microsoft Vi.

Comment: Microsoft Vi: http://pics.livejournal.com/allah_sulu/pic/0005832c

Comment: Or install `cygwin`

Answer (score 2):

I use [whereis](http://www.flounder.com/whereis.htm) written by Joseph M. Newcomer (co-author of Win32 Programming).

Answer (score 1):

Nope, no native equivalent.  Can't even get command completion with `^F` in a `cmd /f:on` shell, more's the pity.

You can always install a Windows port of a Unix shell environment to get `which`, of course.

Comment: Did you try pressing the Tab key for completion?

Comment: No, since that's not a Windows cmd.exe completion character, and it doesn't do anything...

Comment: Strange, I always used Tab for tab-completion, it worked even on fresh installs.

Comment: ...though I'm not sure now what /f does. (My phone doesn't have cmd.exe)

Comment: Check cmd /? when you have it on hand.  It goes on for a while about how it enables ^F for file completion and ^D for directory completion, and how to tweak it.  Wish I knew how to turn out this tab completion. :)

Comment: Maybe try TweakUI?

Answer (score 1):

You have this with PowerShell. If you don't have PS you can [get it](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2003/technologies/management/powershell/default.mspx) from Microsoft. It's free.

Here is an article from [Linux-Magazine](http://www.linux-magazine.com/issues/2007/78/shell_games/(kategorie)/0) which touches on the topic of Unix (bash) commands available in PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Server 2003/2008 has "where" built in.

Comment: ...or is it in the Reskit/Support Tools.  No, I'm sure it's in CMD.EXE...

Answer (score -1):

And if your program is interactive you can always check the Task manager. Select the process you want to explore, and choose "Open file Location" from the popup meny

Comment: I'm sorry, but this does not answer the question being asked. This only provides the path of a running file. The question is asking to find what executable will get called when a command without a path is executed.